# map single source schema element to multiple element with attribute

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a `source schema` as follows:

```
Users
  Id
  Name
  Department
```

and `destination schema` as follows:

```
Employee
  Name
  Number
    number_type(attribute)
```

I need to do the following mapping

```
Name ---> Name
Id ---> Number (number_type = "Id")
Department_no  --> Number (number_type = "dept")
```

I need to map both `Id and department number i.e. 2 elements to 1 element` i.e. `Number in dest schema` but for both attribute value should be different.

Input

```
<Users>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Department_no>456</Department_no>
</Users>
```

Output:

```
<Employee>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Number number_type = "Id">123</Number>
    <Number number_type = "dept">456</Number>
</Employee>
```

How can I achieve in BizTalk or what could be the inline XSLT for the same?

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't very clear.  Do you need to concat the values?  Can you post **examples** of the input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Johns-305. I have added Input and Output examples

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  But...I don't see what the problem is.  You just have to map the values, there's nothing even slightly complicated about this.  Are we missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You nearly have it

```
Name ---> Name
Id ---> Number
Department  --> Number
```

Then also link both Id & Department to a looping functoid that goes to Number

Plus to do the attributes there are some things you can try such as

```
Id ---> number_type 
Department -->  number_type
```

But click on the links select Copy Name instead of the Copy Text value.

[image: BizTalk Map image]

From an input

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO55049939Input">
  <Users>
    <Id>Id_0</Id>
    <Name>Name_0</Name>
    <Department>Department_0</Department>
  </Users>
</ns0:Root>
```

You will get output

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO55049939output">
    <Employee>
        <Name>Name_0</Name>
        <Number number_type="Id">Id_0</Number>
        <Number number_type="Department">Department_0</Number>
    </Employee>
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: I needed the value "dept" in the attribute. So did it with custom XSLT. Anyway it was helpful. Thanks!!